# Duda en C# sintetizador

Tags: c#

soy bastante nuevo usando c# y por diversion estoy siguiendo un video para programar un sintetizador y me surgieron un par de dudas.
La liga del video es la siguiente: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fp1Snqq9ovw&list=PLuF1v-3Fw9gpIMC5eZFc-Op_3eFKwzHa4
Bueno mis dos preguntas:
En el minuto 12:45 ejecuta el codigo sin usar el boton start, luego se remarcan en amarillo las lineas de codigo y comienza a obtener registros, Como hago eso (tanto ejecutar de esa manera como obtener dichos registros)?

La segunda pregunta, En el minuto 18:09 se usan los recursos "memorystream" y "binarywriter", al escribirlos me aparecen como error, alguien sabra porque ocurre esto?

gracias

Comment: Se corre con f5 , o crl+ f5 sin depurador, en cuanto al error es por que debes importar las librerías ctrol+enter cuando estas posicionado sobre la linea que te marca error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es el depurador de visual estudio, si se fija en la parte izquierda de las líneas, él coloca un punto, este punto en rojo, este es un punto de interrupción, este al llegar a esa parte detiene la ejecución, para validar la información que pasa en este lugar.

Teclas para navegar.

`F5` => Continua con la ejecución o para saltar al siguiente punto
`F9` => Agregar o quitar punto en la que se encuentra posicionado
`F10` => Salta a la siguiente linea

Respecto a `memorystream` y a `binarywriter` debe tener en cuenta las mayusculas como las minusculas, en el caso de que estas se encuentren bien, puede que no este importando las using correspondiente `using System.IO;`